# How do I understand packets?

Tags: python, server, udp, packet

I am creating server software in Python.

I'm also using https://wiki.vg/Bedrock_Protocol which has documented the protocol that I am using.
According to this site, the client will send a login packet with an id of `0x01`, and then it has three fields.

This packet when I receive it is a bunch of what I think is binary (stuff like `0x00` or `0x01`).

So how do I figure out the id of the packet and the values of the fields from Python? Is there any documentation?

For those who want to know what I have tried, to get the id I did `packet[0]`, but I am not sure if this is the correct way, and I still have no idea how the fields are separated.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `struct.pack()` and `struct.unpack()` to manipulate fields in a packet.

Comment: You can also use a library such as https://github.com/BluCodeGH/bedrock

Comment: @Barmar That library is for worlds, not servers.

Comment: How about https://github.com/PrismarineJS/bedrock-protocol. I just googled "python bedrock protocol" and found both of them. This one has examples of both client and server.

Comment: @Barmar How do I know which format to use for struct.unpack?

Comment: The documentation you linked to has the structure of every type of packet. You read the first byte containing the packet ID, and use that to determine the format of the rest of the packet.